# Вопрос по обработке больших данных в Maria DB

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, big-data, squid

Имеется задача обработки и аналитики логов.
Объем логов относительно большой: за сутки около 50 миллионов строк, 20 ГБ в таблице СУБД MiriaDB, движок INNODB. Простейшие запросы, типа выгрузки топ-10 посещаемых доменах за сутки выполняются несколько минут, а в дальнейшем требуется проводить аналитику, например, по месяцам.
Существуют ли Open Source решения для подобной аналитики, либо СУБД, работающие по аналогии с MSSQL OLAP?

Comment: Предрасчёта с вменяемой дискретностью (скажем, почасовой) более чем достаточно - логи-то задним числом не меняются? А на базе таких промежуточных данных статистики считаются влёт, особенно если с индексами не накосячить.

Comment: логи приходят раз в сутки (прокси пишет их в большой файл) и парсятся по ночам.

Comment: Для аналитики в любом случае лучше хранить уже агрегированные данные. Чудес не бывает, поднять с диска 20 Гб и обработать занимает время. что бы было быстро надо принимать целый комплекс мер: Хранить данные в правильном виде. Делать нужные индексы. Возможно вносить некоторую избыточность, если это позволяет ускорить конкретные медленные операции. Особое внимание обратить на первичный ключ таблицы, надо не забывать, что inndb хранит таблицу в дереве по первичному ключу. А следовательно обработка в порядке первичного ключа в несколько раз быстрее любых других

Comment: Ну вот в процессе парсинга последним шагом и посчитать укрупнёнку. Согласись, имея почасовое обращение, получить суточный топ-10 - это тьфу, и растереть. А если минимальная дискретность аналитики - сутки, так сразу посуточно и считать. А ещё укрупнённую статистику можно нормализовать - скажем, те же домены вынести в отдельную таблицу, и пополнять отсутствующими,- так за счёт только компактности уже получится неслабый профит.

Comment: [Не](https://mariadb.com/products/mariadb-platform-analytical/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Рекомендую обратить внимание на ClickHouse: https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/ru/